# Angular ng-repeat doesn't work in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get an ng-repeat to work in an Angular directive test, but the view doesn't update when $scope variables are updated and $digest() is called.

```
'use strict';

describe('Asset tests', function() {
    var $compile,
        $rootScope,
        $scope,
        $timeout,
        templateHtml = '<span ng-repeat="asset in assets">{{asset.id}}</span>',
    view;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('my.module');
        inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $timeout = _$timeout_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            $scope.assets = [];
            $scope.selectedItems = [];
            $scope.deleteAsset = function() {
                console.log('yay');
            };
            view = angular.element(templateHtml);
            $compile(view)($scope);
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    });

    describe('Testing some stuff', function() {
        it('should test some stuff', function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
                $scope.assets.push({id:i, name: 'Rad ' + i});
            };
            $scope.$digest();
            console.log(view);
            console.log(jQuery('span').length);
        });
    });
});
```

Log statements output:

```
LOG: {0: <span ng-repeat="assets in assets">{{asset.id}}</span>, length: 1}   
LOG: 56
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you html template is compiling correctly. It says `assets in assets` and should be `asset in assets`. Try that.

Plus, I think you aren't compiling the right thing. You are compiling the text template but not the actual view element.

```
view = angular.element(templateHtml);
$compile(view)($scope);
```

Comment: thanks for pointing those things out.  Still getting the same result.  See edit of original code.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but I came across a similar issue so I post what worked for me.
My problem was in the template. I needed to add a div or something to wrap the span that had the ng-repeat. In this case changing from:

```
templateHtml = '<span ng-repeat="asset in assets">{{asset.id}}</span>'
```

to

```
templateHtml = '<div><span ng-repeat="asset in assets">{{asset.id}}</span></div>'
```

would do the trick.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Certainly did help (with a jest test). Thanks